# No SSL traffic from Google Analytics

Tags: ssl, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I need to add all traffic generated by google analytics to a "free of charge" traffic whitelist for mobile devices. But that whitelist does not support HTTPS connections.

Do Google Analytics send requests to somewhere, anytime, through SSL/HTTPS?

Is there a way to prevent it from exchange any traffic between the client and the server through SSL? So that no request on the webpage is made on HTTPS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Analytics.js, the requests should handle both http and https.  Looking at the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#forceSSL):

"By default, tracking beacons sent from https pages will be sent using https while beacons sent from http pages will be sent using http. Setting forceSSL to true will force http pages to also send all beacons using https."